# Messed with grub display parameter. Now no display on boot and no boot menu too

Tags: grub2

I have a HP Pavilion G6 laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 on it.
It all started when I tried to connect the LG monitor to my laptop via a HDMI cable and though the background used to appear on the monitor, the icons or mouse did not appear. It was a static screen.

Foolishly I should say, I googled it and found a link (which solved that particular issue) where it was said to modify the GRUB file (I believe `grub.cfg`) where 
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` is replaced with something as `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nouveau.modset=0"`
Actually I don't even remember now what I changed it to. I could not find the link where i got it from.

And then I rebooted.

Now I am surprised to find that I can just see a blank screen with <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key blinking.

I thought of fixing the GRUB file by booting of a live USB, but I can't even get the boot menu (by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>F10</kbd> etc.)

Again googling I see that <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> blinking is associated with a CPU/RAM issue, but I am pretty surprised how did changing the GRUB entry affect the CPU?

Anyone can shed a light on what might have gone wrong, and if at all I can fix it?

Comment: it would be better if you can provide that mysterious link, it would help a lot more further readers

Comment: Sorry, but i tried a lot to find the exact link but could not get hold of it.. But i have edited my answer with a bit more recollection of what i changed with

Comment: @user180630 ok this is completely a wild guess but has worked for me in similar situations. Does the laptop have easily removable battery? If yes, you could try this: disconnect the power supply, remove the battery, then press and hold power button for more than 12 seconds, put the battery back in and try booting the laptop.

Comment: @user180630 Also, what's the blinking pattern of Caps Lock light? Here's a page with information on the flashing light and beeping error codes, and how to resolve the problem: `https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01732674`

Comment: @Jags i dont know how to thank you, but that worked. Pressing the power button for more than 12 sec after taking the battery out and without power supply, didnt make sense to me, but i just tried. I reiserted the battery pack and started, and i am back. Is pressing power button without any power input some kind of hard reset?

Comment: @user180630 I'm glad that your laptop is back on :) and yes, pressing and holding the power button AFTER (1) disconnecting AC power supply and (2) Removing battery will reset "clears all information from the computer's memory". Here's another HP page with more info: `https://support.hp.com/ie-en/document/c01684768`

Answer (score 0):

Since my suggestion has resolved the issue, I'm gonna post it as an answer.

If the laptop have easily removable battery:

```
1, Please disconnect the AC power supply,
2, Remove the battery,
3, Then press and hold power button for more than 12 seconds,
4, Put the battery back in,
5, Try booting the laptop normally.
```

Also, for anyone else comes across this, here are HP support pages with more information on the flashing light and beeping error codes, and how to resolve the problems:

(1) HP Notebook PCs - Computer Does Not Start and Emits an LED or Beep Code:

`https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01732674`

(2) HP Notebook PCs - How to Power Reset your Laptop​:

`https://support.hp.com/ie-en/document/c01684768`